# After executing "npm start" command, the code was "COMPILED SUCCESSFULLY" and redirected me to the web browser. But there wasn't any output

Tags: reactjs

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';

import './App.css';
import {Route} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Route path="/"  component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/about"  component={About}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
 render(){
return(
    <div>
    <h1>Home </h1>
    
    
    </div>

)


 }
  }

export default Home;
```

About.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class About extends Component {
 render(){
return(
    <div>
    <h1>About</h1>
    
    
    </div>

)


 }
  }

export default About;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-router-native": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: There seem to be no web page that hosts the app. Is it missing? I've assembled a tiny tutorial you can follow https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2021/10/visual-studio-code-typescript-react-how.html

Answer (score 1):

you need to setup an router and an switch for your routes to work. [docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

change your app.js to

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';

import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
           <Switch>
               <Route path="/"  component={Home}/>
               <Route path="/about"  component={About}/>
           </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you. But not working